# Why does this index work? c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

All,  my professor gave us the following loop for use in this weeks assignment:

```
char *ptr1, *ptr2;  
char c;
ptr1 = &arr[0];  
ptr2 = &arr[idx-1];

while(ptr1 < ptr2){
  c     = *ptr1;  
  *ptr1 = *ptr2;
  *ptr2 = c;

  ptr1++;
  ptr2--;
}
```

Is this about the position of ptr1 vs. ptr2? The program reverses a c_str and works just fine, I just don't understand why.

Comment: Code has been fixed. Is it because they point to the same array?

Comment: As both pointers now are related, it's okay to compare them like you do.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Never mind. I'm wrong; it's unspecified. And now since there's a C tag in there, who knows, since it's undefined in C and unspecified in C++.

Comment: To understand what the code does, step though it line by line in a debugger, checking the values of all variables. It should tell you how it works.

Comment: It basically swaps the first and last letter, then the second first with the second last, then the third...

Answer (score 8):

Do you have a problem understanding any of the individual statements? If not, then seeing how it works is just a question of going through the steps.

The first three statements of the loop swap the character pointed by `ptr1` and the one pointed by `ptr2`. Initially, `ptr1` and `ptr2` point to the first and last characters of the string. The second pass, they are pointing to the second and the second-last characters of the string, etc.

Initially:

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
arr --> |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  | NUL |    c |  ?  |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
           ^                       ^
           |                       |
          ptr1                    ptr2
```

After `c = *ptr1;`:

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
arr --> |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  | NUL |    c |  a  |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
           ^                       ^
           |                       |
          ptr1                    ptr2
```

After `*ptr1 = *ptr2;`:

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
arr --> |  e  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  e  | NUL |    c |  a  |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
           ^                       ^
           |                       |
          ptr1                    ptr2
```

After `*ptr2 = c;`:

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
arr --> |  e  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  a  | NUL |    c |  a  |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
           ^                       ^
           |                       |
          ptr1                    ptr2
```

After `ptr1++; ptr2--;`:

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
arr --> |  e  |  b  |  c  |  d  |  a  | NUL |    c |  a  |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
                 ^           ^
                 |           |
                ptr1        ptr2
```

After another pass:

```
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
arr --> |  e  |  d  |  c  |  b  |  a  | NUL |    c |  b  |
        +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+
                      ^ ^
                      | |
                   ptr1 ptr2
```

Loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a string.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| t | h | i | s |   | i | s |   | f | o | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now let's say `ptr1` and `ptr2` point to:

```
ptr1                                    ptr2
|                                       |
v                                       v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| t | h | i | s |   | i | s |   | f | o | o |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

at the start of the `while` loop. You can now follow the lines in the
`while` loop one step at a time to understand why the code reverses the
string.